# How can I execute a URI in the corresponding application in C#?

Tags: c#, uri

I would like to execute the URI `skype:username?chat` from a C# .NET application, however, I would like it to do it as if it was typing the URI in the Run box and hitting OK. For some Windows 8 or newer computers, they will be running the modern version of Skype, and I can't call `C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe skype:username?chat` if they don't have it on their desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method with the URI to execute as the parameter.